# power spectral density from CTFT to DTFT

Tags: fourier-transform

How to compute $|\alpha(e^{j2 \pi f})|^2$, the power spectral density of a discrete-time signal $\alpha_n = \alpha(nT) \in \{\pm1\}$ from the power spectral density of the corresponding continuous-time Fourier Transform of $\alpha(t)$, $|\alpha(f)|^2$?

Also what is the relation between $|\alpha(e^{j2 \pi fT})|^2$ and $|\alpha(e^{j2 \pi f})|^2$, where $T$ is the constant sampling period?

Comment: see the [Shannon theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist%E2%80%93Shannon_sampling_theorem#Aliasing), sampling in the time domain corresponds to periodization in the Fourier domain : with $A(f) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty a(t) e^{-2i \pi f t} dt$ and $B(f) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a(nT) e^{-2i \pi f n T}$ you have $B(f) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty A(f+k/T)$

Comment: @user1952009, how do we define the psd using the DTFT, over only one period of $B(f)$?

Comment: $|B(f)|^2{}{}{}{}$...

Comment: @user1952009, but that is infinity since $B(f)$ is periodic.

Comment: no. $A(f)$ is finite whenever $a(t) \in L^1$, i.e. $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |a(t)| dt < \infty$, and $B(f)$ is finite whenever $a(n T) \in l^1$, i.e. $\sum_n |a(nT)| < \infty$. try with $a(t) = \cos(2\pi t/T)$ if $|t| < T/2$, $a(t) = 0$ otherwise

Comment: I edited the post. $a_n \in \{\pm 1\}$, a random equiprobable sequence of $\pm 1$. so $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |a(t)| dt \not < \infty$.

Comment: if $a(t) \not \in L^1$ but $a(t) = 0$ for $t < 0$,  then consider instead $A(s) = \int_0^\infty e^{-st} a(t)$, i.e. the Laplace transform and $B(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a(nT) z^{-n}$ the z-transform, so that $B(r e^{2i \pi f}) = \sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty A(r+2i \pi (f+k/T))$